# Asp.NET Web Api Routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following code in my WebApiConfig.cs

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Action",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

ABCController.cs

```
 public class ABCController : ApiController
 {        
     [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
     [ActionName("GetABCByXYZById")]
     public string GetABCByXYZById(int xYZId)
     {                
         return "GetABCByXYZById";
     }
 }
```

When I try to call the API it says not able to find the action in the controller.

```
 /api/ABC/GetABCByXYZById/12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your routeTemplate uses the name `{id}` for the action parameter but your action actually takes in a parameter with name `xYZId`.

Try changing your action parameter to called `id` and it should work:
`public string GetABCByXYZById(int id)`